# Responsibility for the performance of students

Tags: responsibilities

As an educator, how much responsibility do you place upon yourself for the performance of your students? Whether that be in the role of lecturer, TA, thesis supervisor, etc. Of course there are many factors that go into the performance of a student- though surely the role of teacher is at the heart of it. There will always be some students who will do well regardless of whom is teaching them, but in many cases, the influence of a teacher can be the difference between whether a student passes or fails, decides to major in the subject, pursue an academic career in the same field, etc.

Thanks

Comment: As it is phrased now the question is primarily opinion based, which is why I voted to close the question. This does not mean I think it is a bad question. I suspect you can turn this question is something fitting to this forum if you focus the question more by specifying why you want to know this.

Comment: What's wrong with opinions? Opinions are pretty much what I want here.

Comment: @Carol Please peruse the help pages, e.g., [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

My physics teacher in school said that the educator part is 50%, and the rest is the student's responsibility. She was talking about interested students.

Instead of thinking of how much responsibility you should place upon yourself while teaching, you should ask what are your responsibilities as a teacher, depending on the objective you have chosen for your teaching.

For example, if you have beginners who need the subject, you are responsible to create the environment that fosters their learning. That means to create meaningful assignments, balanced exams, encourage collaboration, etc. You are responsible to adapt your teaching style if you can increase the student's learning efficiency.

You are in no way responsible for your students decisions. If they chose not to care, there is little reason to beat yourself up. Once you created the environment for them, there isn't much else you can do. As a professor, there is little chance that you'll have enough time to help people individually beyond office hours.